# Why are there so many READ operations with a function that loads a single document?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a Flutter application that loads a `document` from Cloud Firestore and displays its content in a `BottomSheet` widget.

The read is performed on a `collection` (named *details*) that has almost 4K `documents` in it. Also, each `document` has a complex JSON, where the requested data is. This JSON has 2 simple `Map` objects, one `array` and up 10 `Strings`.

I want to read a single `document` from *details* for displaying it on the `BottomSheet`, so I request the desired `document` with an specific given `id` in `initState()`, upon the creation of the `BottomSheet`.

```
// CustomBottomSheet Widget

CustomData info;

@override
void initState() {
    _getDocument();
    super.initState();
}

Future<void> _getDocument() async {
    final FirebaseFirestore _fireStoreReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    try {
        await _fireStoreReference.collection("details").doc(widget.uid).get().then((snapshot) {
            if (snapshot != null && snapshot.exists) {
                setState(() { 
                    // fromJson is a factory method from CustomData to translate
                    // the Map<String, dynamic> from Firebase into a 
                    // CustomData Object
                    info = CustomData.fromJson(snapshot.data());
                });
            }
        });
    } catch (err) {
        //...
    }
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomSheet(
        onClosing: () => {},
        builder: (context) {
            return Container(
                child: // Display data of CustomData
            )
        }
    );
}
```

```
// CustomBottomSheet Widget is called from the Main Page as so

...
GestureDetector(
    onTap: () async {
        await showModalBottomSheet(context: context,
            isScrollControlled: true,
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            isDismissible: false,
            builder: (context) {
                return CustomBottomSheet(uid: "0001");
            }
        ).then((_) { 
            // Uploads some UI when BottomSheet is closed
        });
    },
    child: Container(width: 150, height: 90, color: Colors.orange, child: Text("Show Data"))
),
...
```

This query should cost only 1 `READ` operation, but whenever I show the `BottomSheet`, Cloud Firestore charges me with +7K `READ` operations. This morning I went from having 619 reads to 8.2K reads only after requesting a single `document` of "details".

My thoughts were that I was somehow requesting it that many times or perhaps that the JSON inside each `document` is so complex and large that it costs exactly that amount of `READ` operations each time I request it. With these things in mind, I searched for answers, but everywhere I read says that **reading one `document`, no matter what is inside, it will cost 1 `READ`**.

I also debugged the application and, as expected, `initState()` is only called once and therefore, the `document` is read only once on execution, so I do not know from where these insane amounts of `READ` operations come from.

Furthermore, it came into my mind that just looking up the 4K `documents` inside *details* **on the Firebase Console** maybe is correlated to the problem, as you are requesting the reading of those documents as you scroll by them. But I do not know.

Comment: You should first await the result. For exmaple: `var res = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('yourCollection').doc('yourId).get().then((value)=>value.data());`, And then set the state: `setState(()=>data=res);`.

Comment: However, I'm not sure if this is the reason you are getting so many document reads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the `READ` operations are being charged within the `Firebase Console`. So, if I request from the app a `document`, the expected `READ` operations will be charged. But if I enter the `Firebase Console` and scroll thorugh all `documents`, the charges skyrocket.